# Prevent QTable from selecting all text on edit

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt

By default, editing an item in a QTable selects all the text within the cell. I want to avoid that. However, I cannot seem to find where this happens.

I wrote a simple custom Delegate which inherits from `QStyledItemDelegate`, and returns a custom object which simply inherits from a `QLineEdit`. In these classes, I tried some combinations of what I thought could do the "trick", such as disabling `QLineEdit::focusInEvent()`, specifying the selection of my `QLineEdit`, but nothing works.

The closest I get is that when I click a cell, I set the selected text I want. But between the moment when the cell is clicked, and the moment when my custom selection is performed, the whole text is selected anyway, which I want to avoid.

Any idea? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coding a custom QLineEdit like this:

```
class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit {
public:
  MyLineEdit(QWidget*parent=0) : QLineEdit(parent)
  {}

  void showEvent(QShowEvent*)
  {
    deselect();
    setSelection(1,2); // should be configurable
  }
};
```

and setting it as editor widget, I can double-click the table cell and obtain a line edit with some pre-selected text without any flickering. Anyway, the entire cell becomes selected in the middle of double-clicking, don't know if this is acceptable for you.